# Only a few CSS files apply their styles in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I am creating a ReactJs app, and am trying to apply styles. I load styles in the normal way (without webpack css modules):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

//styles
import './Header.css';

class Header extends Component {
render() {
    return(
        <div className='header'>
            <h1>Save</h1>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The styles that I have for the header class apply, and everything is groovy. But for about 50% of my ReactJs files and their subsequent CSS files, the class styles do not apply. There is no error either, it finds the CSS and just doesn't apply the styles on *some* of the files.

I have no idea what is wrong, thanks!

**EDIT 1**
The header.css file:

```
 .header {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  text-align: right;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Edit 2**
Example of class whose styles don't apply

Matrix.js:

```
import './Matrix.css';

render() {
    const {users, selectedDivision} = this.state;

    return(
        <div className='container' style={{display:'grid', gridTemplateColumns:'200px 1fr'}}>

            <div style={{textAlign: 'left'}}>
                <input type='text' placeholder="Search Divisions" onChange={(e)=>this.search(e)} className='searchDivs'/>
                <Scroller divisions={this.state.displayDivisions}  handleSelectedDivisionChange={this.handleSelectedDivisionChange.bind(this)} />    
            </div>
            <div style={{marginLeft: '10px'}}>
                <Division division={selectedDivision} users={users} addToParentDivisions={this.handleNewUserAddedToDivision.bind(this)}/>     
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Here my work around has been to use inline styles but I want to try to avoid this as a best practice

**Edit 3**

Looking at dev tools in Chrome it shows that my css is not loaded because they are invalid property values?

[image: Hovering over the exclamation says invalid property value]

So React is loading in the styles, but just refusing to display because they are invalid?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] which shows the code that doesn’t work?

Comment: Can you post the header css file as well?

Comment: @Auriga Added the header.css. Really nothing crazy going on here, just a class

Comment: The text of the question says that the header class works. Can you post an example of a class that doesn't work?

Comment: @AustinMullins Added the matrix.js file

Comment: In the chrome dev tools, it looks like your styling values are getting wrapped as strings.  Did you accidentally do that in some of your css files?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the exact same problem!

**Solution: Remove quotation marks (") around your property values.**

Inline styles in JS require them but CSS does not.

I work in CSS every day I should've known this. 
VSCode didn't pick it up either.
(Facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else is working properly like importing the right css file, using className, etc. I've found that, on rare occasions, something gets stuck in the browser cache and needs a full refresh.

Mac: Command+shift+R

Win: Ctrl+shift+R

Comment: Do you have a copy of matrix.css?

Comment: Another question...is the import line and filename the same case? If the import asks for Header.css and the filename is header.css, that can cause problems sometimes

Comment: the import and the filename are the same case

Comment: Based on your updated post, it looks like the styles are being overwritten, likely by a browser default. You can go through the rest of the dev tools and it should show where the styles are actually coming from. As a bad idea, you can set `!important` to a css item, but it's a really bad idea

Comment: yea I want to try and avoid that. It seems bizarre that if I use inline styles it works fine, but when I try to import everything breaks

Comment: Inline styles are the highest level so they'll always supercede anything that isn't set as !important. That being said, setting an ID on a higher element then in the css file saying `#parent .header h1` should override the browser defaults. There are also css files like Normalize.css that can clear out all browser defaults before the page loads.